# Is it a good idea to duplicate a View Controller to create almost equal scene?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, swift3

I have a game done and I want to create a multiplayer mode so I have duplicated the `GameViewController` with the intention to create the multiplayer scene.

Now when I tap the single player button it shows the `GameViewController` and when I tap the multiplayer it triggers a function that verify if the user is authenticated and then performs a segue with identifier `AAA` to the copy/pasted `GameViewController`.

Now the problem is that I want the multiplayer part to have a completely different logic but I want to use most of the functionality and the layout  of the `GameViewController` and I wonder if there is a way to clone it and then change its class but maintain at least the layout?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Place some code if you want to. I would probably choose a way using one controller with conditions that would route difference between your segues to single player / multiplayers views. But it depends on how robust is the code and how many differences occur in that controller.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be a subclass?